# What is a Star Trek Couch?

Tags: star-trek

I've seen the pictures from Fog Creek Software's offices of their Star Trek couch.  Why is that a Star Trek couch?  Was the same style of couch used on-set of TNG or something?

[image]

<sup>From [Fogcreek.com](http://www.fogcreek.com/about.html)</sup>

Comment: Doesn't that huge ring magnet cause problems with electronics?  I'd think twice before setting my phone down on that table.

Comment: @Simon it's Manhattan, practicality stands before vogue like a leaf before the tsunami.

Comment: A friend of mine had a similar one, his father created a company incorporated as Diagnostic Chemicals Ltd.
We used to call it the mothership

Comment: Whoa, it seems my college bought all the library furniture from the Star Trek excess department.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The couch pictured **above** is actually downstairs in the Fog Creek office.

Stack Exchange has its own Star Trek couch (I'm told it was purchased because Joel specifically said it looks like a Star Trek couch). Here's a picture of one of its sections:

[image]

It's actually gray and purple; it came out blue in the photo. So...

[image]

I see a color scheme resemblance.

Comment: I can personally confirm the veracity of this. :D

Comment: This is the Star Trek couch.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky where did you guys find that?

Comment: That is, unquestionably, a Star Trek Couch. I think it would stay a Star Trek Couch even if you changed the photo's blue to red or purple.

Comment: It looks like a TNG bridge console that someone turned into a couch.

Comment: I see it as white-gold.

Comment: @Trollwut really? I see blue & black.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky can we please have a link to the entire couch? Thank you! <3

Answer (score 16):

On both Star Trek The Next Generation, in counselor Deanna Troi's office and in Star Trek Voyager in Captain Janeway's office there were these partitioned winding snaking couches lining a section of a room or wall of the exact same design as the one in the Fog Creek offices.

In the late 1980s and early 90s these were considered to be minimalist and futuristic-looking designs with lines and contours that flowed agreeably with the design of the surrounding sets aka the 24th century starship. Examples of these can be seen by googling images of either "Janeway ready room" or "Troi's office"

[image]

Comment: I don't think you're wrong, but can you offer any proof that there's a connection?

Comment: @Richard - The picture itself would seem to be valid proof for an affirmative answer to the question "Was the same style of couch used on-set of TNG or something?", even if there's no definitive proof that this is what the people at Fog Creek Software were thinking of when they named their couch (but it does seem like a very strong likelihood).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - The sofa in janeway's lounge only bears a passing resemblance to the one in the photo.

Comment: @Richard - I think you're being too literal, the shape is obviously not identical but it's definitely "the same style". It's not common for couches to have a series of curved cushions which produce an overall smooth curved shape (both including S-curves), and the answer suggests this was even less common "in the late 1980s and early 90s".

Comment: @Hypnosifl - If you look at the accepted answer, it's clear that the curvy couch (picture in the original question) isn't actually the Star Trek Couch they were referring to.

Comment: @Richard - Are you sure the main answer was saying the original question was wrong in its label? When it said "Stack Exchange has its own Star Trek couch", I interpreted it to mean "its own Star Trek couch distinct from the downstairs one at the Fog Creek Software office". [This meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53250/what-role-does-fog-creek-software-have-in-the-ownership-of-the-stack-exchange-ne) indicates Fog Creek and Stack Exchange are now different companies, although maybe at the time the couch was named they weren't.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - My reading of [Joel's comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/what-is-a-star-trek-couch/83892?noredirect=1#comment10630_6495) was that the OP has mis-identified which couch the blog post was referring to.

Comment: @Richard - Ah, thanks, I just read Brett's answer but missed Joel Spolsky's "That's not it" comment (user43031 probably missed it too, or didn't realize Joel worked at Stack Exchange).

Comment: Yes, Joel corrected me, and he would be considered a canonical source.  So the accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's the cool couch pictured on their web site's About page [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/).

Judging by that web page's content, I assume it's just a cool 1960's-looking couch. They probably watch Star Trek from that couch on the big plasma TV they mention. They are programmers after all. (What better to watch when taking a break from some code you're thrashing on?)

Comment: This is not the Star Trek Couch.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky what you should have said is, "This is not the Star Trek couch you are looking for."  Or am I mixing my SciFi references?